# Why does public overload conflict with private using directive on some compilers?

Tags: c++, inheritance, using-directives

I came across the following situation in one of my projects, where a base class has a function template, which is hidden by a non-templated function in a derived class template.  Further down the class hierarchy, the non-templated function is explicitly bringing the function into the scope via a using directive.

Here's a simplified example code:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
  template<typename T> const T& get() const;
};

template<typename T> class Derived : public Base
{
private:
  using Base::get;
public:
  const T& get() const;
};

template<typename T> class MoreDerived : public Derived<T>
{
public:
  using Derived<T>::get; // <-- this causes the problem

  const T& call_get() {
    return get();
  }
};

template class MoreDerived<int>;
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/5MQ0VL

The above code fails on GCC and Clang with errors like:

```
<source>:15:28: error: 'template<class T> const T& Base::get() const' is inaccessible within this context

   15 | template<typename T> class MoreDerived : public Derived<T>
```

MSVC and ICC accept this code without complaints.

I'm wondering, why the compilers complain about `Base::get<T>` while there *is* a public overload `Derived<T>::get` available?

Removing the private `using Base::get` from `Derived<T>` leads to warnings about hiding functions from the base class. So this is unfortunately also not an ideal option.

Without the `using Derived<T>::get`, calls to `get` have to be qualified within `MoreDerived` as it would not be a dependent name otherwise.

Any ideas, what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Actually, it's never a good idea to make public members of base classes private in derived ones; you violate the "is a" relation ship. What about: `Derived<int> d; d.get<double>(); /* won't compile, but need: */ static_cast<Base>(d).get<double>();`

Comment: I understand your concern, but making `get<U>` fail to compile for `Derived<T>` is actually a feature of the original code.

Comment: Is your question "why is it resolving to the non-`const` overload", or is it "why is the `using` declaration pulling in private declarations"?

Comment: @zneak: I'm not seeing any non-`const` overloads of `get`?  So it's rather the latter. :-)

Comment: Is it a requirement to inherit from `Base` publicly? Private inheritance should solve the issue. If `Base` *needs* to be inherited publicly, but the template getter shall be hidden anyway, you simply could make it protected – or you might move it to *another* base class that will be inherited privately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what applies here is [[namespace.udecl]/17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#17):

> **In a *using-declarator* that does not name a constructor, all members of the set of introduced declarations shall be accessible.** In a *using-declarator* that names a constructor, no access check is performed. In particular, if a derived class uses a *using-declarator* to access a member of a base class, the member name shall be accessible. **If the name is that of an overloaded member function, then all functions named shall be accessible.** […]

(emphasis mine) in combination with [[namespace.udecl]/19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#19):

> A synonym created by a *using-declaration* has the usual accessibility for a *member-declaration*. […]

The using declaration in `MoreDerived` creates a synonym for `Derived::get` which itself is a synonym for the overload set consisting of the member function `Derived::get` and the member function template `Base::get`. The latter is not accessible at the point of the using declaration in `MoreDerived` (because it is private in `Derived`). Thus, GCC and Clang are correct, this code should not compile. Moving the using declaration in `Derived` from the private to the public part, for example

```
template<typename T> class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  using Base::get;
  const T& get() const;
};
```

resolves the issue…

Comment: Not sure this is the whole story - the code compiles just fine if you turn `Base::get` into an ordinary member function (`const int& get() const;`).

Comment: @lubgr I'd say when you turn `Base::get` into an ordinary member function, then `Derived::get` (which also is an ordinary member function) will hide it and, thus, the problem disappears…

Comment: @michael-kenzel Thanks for your reply! The reference to the standard helps a lot. So you're saying that the function template `get<T>` is not hidden by `get`?

Comment: @pah Exactly. An ordinary member function cannot hide a member function template. Functions and function templates are two different kinds of things. Intuitively, consider that a member function template essentially defines a whole set of potential functions itself, so one function alone cannot possibly hide that entire set…

Answer (score 1):

[Michael Kenzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064761/michael-kenzel) already explained nicely [why your code did fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252035/1312382).

> [...] but making get fail to compile for Derived is actually a feature of the original code

Although I cannot encourage such a pattern, as you are violating the "is a" relationship, the following might do the trick for you:

```
class Base
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  const T& get() const;
};

template<typename T> class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    template<typename U>
    U const& get() const = delete;
    T const& get() const { return Base::get<T>(); }
};
```

Probably a better option is to simply make the template getter protected instead.

Private inheritance of `Base` should solve the issue as well, if that's feasible for you; if not, another option might be moving the template getter to a new, separate base class which then will be inherited privately.

Both variants would prevent

```
Derived<int> d;
static_cast<Base>(d).get<double>();
```

as well, if this is meaningless anyway.

Comment: In my case, the `Derived<T>::get` is an optimization and does not delegate to `Base::get<T>`.  You *could* call `get<T>` through a base pointer, which will give you the slower implementation (and return the same value at the end).

Moving forward, I think I will skip the `using` in `MoreDerived` and qualify the calls inside `MoreDerived` instead.

Comment: @pah Calling the base variant is just an example for implementation, of course you could replace it with *any* other one... The interesting part about is *`delete`ing* the template variant.

Comment: Yes, the explicit `delete` of the template variant would be an alternative to skipping the `using` from `MoreDerived`, thanks.

Comment: @pah You're welcome – anyway, think about the better alternatives. Do you *really* need the template getter to be public in `Base`?